# How can I strip trailing full stop (period) from text nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

if I have a text node with a trailing full stop (or period in US english) what expression can I use to strip the full stop and leave the remainder?

e.g input

```
<ol>
<li>This is the first item.</li>
<li>This is the second</li>
<li>This is the 3rd. </li>
</ol>
```

required output

```
<ol>
<li>This is the first item</li>
<li>This is the second</li>
<li>This is the 3rd</li>
</ol>
```

I have this but it seems unnecessarily cumbersome

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ol"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="li"/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates select="text()" mode="clean-text"/></li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="clean-text">
        <xsl:variable name="normal-text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($normal-text,string-length($normal-text),1) = '.'"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($normal-text,1,string-length($normal-text)-1))"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$normal-text"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a cleverer way to achieve the same thing?
BTW I am using v1.0 as this may be instantiated in a Microsoft environment.
But a v2.0 solution would be of interest too

TIA

Comment: Actually what you have is not bad. It has the advantage of only normalizing the spaces once. What is "cumbersome" is all the other templates that can be replaced by the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template.

Comment: But identity transform would only replace root and ol templates, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it could replace all your templates except the last one - for which the match pattern could be `li/text()` (and no mode is necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you have the `replace` function:

```
  <xsl:template match="ol/li[ends-with(normalize-space(.), '.')]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\.\s*$', '')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1 enviroments you can often call into the underlying platform (e.g. Java or .NET or PHP or Python) to make use of similar string functions supporting regular expressions like `\.\s*$` to match on the end of a string preceded by zero or more whitespace characters preceded by a single full stop character.

Or try to do it all with pure XPath 1 string functions

```
  <xsl:template match="ol/li[substring(normalize-space(), string-length(normalize-space())) =  '.']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, string-length(normalize-space()) - 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

In all cases, handle copying other stuff through by the identity transformation template: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAW